# ConfusionMatrix. Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels. En R Paquete Caret

Tags: r, rstudio

amigos.
Estoy intentando armar una matriz de confusión para evaluar un modelo lasso.

```
set.seed(1234)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(ephtfmag$P21, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training <- ephtfmag[ inTraining,]
testing  <- ephtfmag[-inTraining,]

modelo1 <- train(P21 ~ .,
               data = training,
               method = "ridge",
               na.action = na.omit,
               preProcess = c("scale", "center"))

predicciones1 <- predict(modelo1, newdata = testing)
```

Todo bien hasta aquí, pero cuando corro la siguiente línea:

```
resultados1  <- confusionMatrix(predicciones1, testing$P21)
```

Aparece el error

```
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels
```

Si consulto nlevels y levels, el resultado es el siguiente:

```
nlevels(predicciones1)
[1] 0
nlevels(testing$P21)
[1] 0
levels(predicciones1)
NULL
levels(testing$P21)
NULL
```

Le estoy dando vuelta a eso y ya he intentado con varias de las respuestas a este problema en el foro pero no encuentro solución. Alguna pista? Gracias!

Comment: Primero que nada ¿qué tipo de variable es P21? dado que estas haciendo un modelo "ridge", entiendo que esta variable debería ser una codificación del tipo 1/0, Si/No, etc. Si es así defínela como un factor  al comienzo de todo.

Comment: Gracias, Patricio. P21 es una variable de ingresos en pesos, no es discreta, así que las categorías son los valores que puede asumir desde $0 hasta el máximo. tenía entendido que ridge y lasso funcionaban para este tipo de regresiones también, o sólo funcionan para las logísticas? perdón si la pregunta es muy básica, soy muy novato en esto

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo tienes un problema de concepto, la [matriz de confusión](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) es una herramienta que muestra la performance de un modelo de clasificación, es una matriz que permite comparar la clasificación real versus la predicción del modelo. En tu caso estas usando un modelo de regresión que entiendo se usa para predecir una variable continua, por lo que no tiene sentido usar una [matriz de confusión](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). Sin embargo para modelos de regresión hay varias herramientas para medir la performance, podemos mencionar algunas:

- R-squared (R2)
- Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE)
- Residual Standard Error (RSE)
- Mean Absolute Error (MAE)

Fuente: [Regression Model Validation](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/38-regression-model-validation/158-regression-model-accuracy-metrics-r-square-aic-bic-cp-and-more/)